# Why ajax call doesn't bind to int[] with jquery .post()

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post

Here is my ajax call:

```
var idsOfRecordsToBeDeleted = [];

        $("#container :checked").each(
            function (index) {
                idsOfRecordsToBeDeleted.push($(this).attr('id'));
            });
var parametersList = { param1: 123456, param2: idsOfRecordsToBeDeleted  };

$.post("/Home/Index", parametersList, function (returnedData) {
    alert(returnedData);
});
```

and there is my controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index( int param1, int[] param2)
{
    return null;
}
```

and param1 is OKAY but param2 is always null. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn traditional on for your jQuery post to allow for shallow array serialization.

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
var parametersList = { param1: 123456, param2: [1, 2, 3, 4] };

$.post("/Home/Index", parametersList, function (returnedData) {
    alert(returnedData);
});
```

If you would like to apply traditional mode to only this post, you can add it with $.ajax.

```
var parametersList = { param1: 123456, param2: [1, 2, 3, 4] };
$.ajax({ 
    url: "/Home/Index",
    type: 'POST',
    data: parametersList
    traditional: true
});
```

Since jQuery 1.8, ajax calls will recursively serialize all objects by defaulting the [traditional flag](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to false.

As a result, deep objects end up getting serialized into a string that represents this object structure:

```
param2[]=1&param2[]=2&param2[]=3&param2[]=4&=param2[]=5
```

ASP.NET MVC doesn't know how to handle this format.  By setting traditional to true, we preserve the structure that ASP.NET MVC expects:

```
param2=1&param2=2&param2=3&param2=4&param2=5
```

**EDIT:**
Based on how you are building your array (attr returns a string), you will end up with an array of strings, not numbers, meaning that MVC will not deserialize your array.

You can confirm the type by inspecting the first element of idsOfRecordsToBeDeleted.

```
typeof(idsOfRecordsToBeDeleted[0])
```

Update your controller method to the following signature:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index( int param1, string[] param2)
```

Comment: I don't know but it doesnt bind somehow in my case. No matter that in Fiddler everything looks fine.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik Have you defined any routes that would prevent both parameters from getting respected properly?  I'd also check that the param2 name matches.

Comment: No, I haven't defined any routes and I have copy/pasted param2 so this is not the problem. When I get it hardcoded(e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4]) it works in your way but the way I am creating the array it just doesnt accept it. I am going to update my question so you can see how I create the actual array.

Comment: Well, I think that I found out what is my mistake. It is that the values that I put into the array are not in the range of the 32 bit integer. They are much bigger. So when I changed to expected type on the server from int[] to string[] it worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the array to a string, then deserialize it on the server.

Client:

```
param2: [1, 2, 3, 4].join(',');
```

Server (Change param2 type to `string` instead of `int[]`):

```
int[] param2Parsed = param2.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```